# Not able to run any script on new list experience forms

Tags: javascript, office-365, list-form

I have to do some customization on a couple of list forms (new, edit).

These lists have the new [list experience mode](https://blogs.office.com/2016/07/25/modern-sharepoint-lists-are-here-including-integration-with-microsoft-flow-and-powerapps/) enabled.

But whenever this mode is enabled I can't seem to be able to:

- Use PreSaveAction
- Add scripts under PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead
- Edit the form page to add in-place webparts

Comment: You are out of luck, Microsofts answer for now is: Switch back to Classic mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only option you have is to turn back to the classic experience at this moment. Right now, Microsoft doesn't allow any branding, theming or customization on the "new list/library experience".

There is a request in Uservoice related to this and MS has given a positive response to it. So, in the future, no timeline defined, we will be able to customize it.

FYI, I tried everything right from script/css injection, themes, custom masterpage, design packages etc. Nothing works.

[Allow Javascript customization and CSS branding/theming in the new Document Library Experience](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th)