# How to customize the SharePoint online ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, ribbon

I have been struggling for 2 days trying to remove the office 365 logo and the SharePoint branding text from the ribbon.

I have tried a lot of [tutorials](https://gilsharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/custom-simplified-top-navigation-in-office-365-SharePoint-online/) but nothing working.

NOTE: I am a complete beginner to SharePoint designer.I seen a lot of CSS as answers on forums but I don't know what to do with them. Also when trying to check in an updated master page i received the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so in order to start branding SharePoint (Office 365) you need 3 things:

- A CSS file
- A place to store the CSS file
- Register/associate the CSS file with the site / master page

### The CSS file

You can use this simple **styles.css** proof-of-concept to tell you it is working.

```
body
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

### Storage

There are many options but it is often suggested to keep your branding resources in the "Style Library".
[image]

### Association

There are many flavors.

If possible, I would suggest `AlternateCSSUrl` property, which is the one you set when you go to Site Settings > Master Page.

[image]

If your version/plan does not support this, you may need to add the call to the master page, under the head section,

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/style library/styles.css %&gt;" runat="server" After="SharepointCssFile" />
```

---

If you managed to get a red(ish) background, you should now be capable of using your browser's "inspect" feature to check the html and what styles you need to override (i.e. include in your css so that they customize the page's elements on top of the current styles).

e.g.

```
.o365cs-base .o365cs-navMenuButton {
    display: none !important;
}
.o365cs-nav-header16 .o365cs-nav-brandingText{
    display: none !important;
}
/*hide the whole left nav*/
.o365cs-nav-header16 .o365cs-nav-leftAlign
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

You may notice some areas are not branded. These are likely lists in modern experience mode and simply cannot be branded. More [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198436/not-able-to-run-any-script-on-new-list-experience-forms).

**Update:**

You should not edit seattle.master directly.
You should create a file on your local computer. Call it CustomMaster.master, copy the contents form seattle.master into it, with the CSS call there.
Upload it and apply it by right-clicking and setting as custom and default master page.

Comment: just to add in Tiago's answer:  @keshav as you are total beginner. To apply Alternative CSS you need to activate **Publishing Feature**  on the particular site you are working on

Comment: @Tiago Duarte i followed the first two steps and i didnt had the option to use alternate css,so i injected the code in seattle.master and publish a major version. NOTE : sharepoint designer keep telling the file has been moved or deleted,,in short couldnt get the red background.

Comment: @Tiajo Duarte Could you show me how to add the code to the master page,i think this is what i have been doing wrongly since the beginnig

Comment: @Tiajo Duarte i found out that i am not able to reference the css files from the master page because i cannot check in the latter,see picture of error in question above

Comment: you typically don't want to edit the out of the box master page. create a copy of seattle.master, apply it and edit that copy instead. place the code just before closing of head tag

Comment: you can't edit the master directly as it contains an html reference. and you should also leave ootb files alone. see updated answer.

Comment: @Tiago Duarte i get  the same problem with a copy of the master page.

Comment: @Tiago Duarte i think i was able to do,when i refresh the page i see momentarily the color i have set for 1-2 second then it goes back to its original color

Comment: @Tiago Duarte i was able to do it by design manager,i set my custom page as master page and i had to clear my cache to see the changes,now the issue is the 0365 button is gone but if i hover it i can still click it,. I tries cursor:not-allowed but i think i missing the ID of the button

Comment: you can try hidding the left nav (answer updated) instead of hiding each navigation item one by one. as long as you managed to have a working css, it's all about understanding how to inspect and use the best and most accurate style classes

Comment: @Tiago Duarte i was able to do it,but now i find that only the navigation for the homepage is affected,if i go to sitepages,they still have the original navigation bar

Comment: it's not just the home page, it's site actions, and all other site pages. problem you have is related to modern experience. see my answer about the topic

Comment: @Tiago Duarte i did go to sharepoint admin page and set the settings to classic view but didnt work,whenver i create a new page it stiil takes the old navigation.AS you mention home and settings page are using the custom navigation

Comment: @Tiago Duarte  Thanks it worked,needed to wait a bit.